# .htaccess redirect foo.com/ to /foo.htm, leave bar.com/ as bar.com

Tags: .htaccess

Note: I had to add spaces because it thought I was posting links...

I have two sites coming into one server and one folder (`foo.com` and `bar.com`).
`Foo.com` needs to point at a page named `foo.htm` under the root of the site.
It also has the requirement of not changing the URL.

If the url is `bar.com` it needs to be left alone.

If the full url is `http://www.foo.com/` it needs to be switched to the equivalent of

```
http://bar.com/foo.htm
```

Does that make sense?

I have the following which works for every page except the root page, which isn't redirecting to `foo.htm`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bar.com/$1
RewriteRule ^$ /foo.htm [L]
```

Comment: Enclose a string like your URLs in backquotes `\`url.com\`` to avoid it being converted to a link

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.bar.com/foo.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bar.com/$1
```

I'm not sure if it will run exactly like this as I can't test it - but if it doesn't work, just modify the regex in RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .... possibly remove the slash and question mark... just try it.